# Convert a string to URI

Tags: android

I need to convert a string to URI, the string is a link to a php file, I can convert it to a Uri through Uri.parse(string) but it needs to be URI in all caps lock in order to insert it in here:

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(link);
```

I don't know the difference between URI and Uri.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it:

```
URI uri = null;
        try {
            uri = new URI(link[0]);
        } catch (URISyntaxException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

`URI` is [`java.net.URI`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URI.html). You create a `URI` via its constructor.